# React - trying to do the add function error = TypeError: state.notes.map is not a function

Tags: reactjs, typeerror

I'm trying to tinker around this todo list app and the add function is throwing an error, can anyone explain why it's throwing off this error?

TypeError: state.notes.map is not a function

App.js file

```js
function reducer(state, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case ACTIONS.ADD_TODO:
            const newTodo = {
                id: Date.now(),
                name: action.payload.name,
                complete: false
            };
            return { ...state, notes: newTodo };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export default function App() {
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, {
        currentNote: null,
        notes: [
            { id: 1, name: 'Eat', complete: true },
            { id: 2, name: 'Eat More', complete: false },
            { id: 3, name: 'Eat Some More', complete: true }
        ]
    });

    const [name, setName] = useState('u');
```

this is where it causes an error

```js
            {state.notes.map(todo => {
                return <Todo key={todo.id} todo={todo} dispatch={dispatch} />;
            })}
```

Comment: You're setting `state.notes = newTodo`. surely you mean to add `newTodo` to the array instead

Comment: thank you! it's working now